# Right-angled triangle prolog construction

Tags: prolog, geometry, pythagorean

I'm to ask a question, which answers are solving this task:

> Which right-angled triangles can be constructed by choosing three sides out of six segments of length being integers from 1 to 6

So, I'm thinking this is essential:

```
between(1,6,X),
between(1,6,Y),
between(1,6,Z),
```

Then we have to make sure it fits Pythagoras statement, so I'm trying this, adding to the above sentence:

```
(X^2 = Y^2 + Z^2 ; 
Y^2 = X^2 + Z^2 ; 
Z^2 = X^2 + Y^2)
```

Also I have been trying to replace `X^2` with `X*X`, but it returns false every time. Why is that?

***From my understanding, I need it to work like this**:
Choose three sides from range 1-6, and make sure they fit Pythagoras statement. (Is triangle disparity also required here? I mean `X>Y+Z,Y>X+Z,Z>X+Y` ?*

Comment: Try `=:=` instead of `=`. Also, you don't need all 3 of those expressions since they'll just give redundant information. Do you really care to distinguish `3,4,5` versus `5,3,4`?

Comment: Well, that's actually good thing you mentioned it. Thanks. I'll be needing this in the future, but here - no, I don't.

By the way, are the only possible answers for this **specified task** `5,3,4` and `5,4,3` ?

You proposed `=:=` since it's a comparise condition, right?

Comment: Check the prolog manual regarding the different comparators, etc. They mean and do various things. `=:=/2` is specifically evaluates arithmetic expressions on either side and checks for equality of results. `=/2` is not an equality operator; it performs prolog *unification*. It's important to know the difference. In your example, limiting all results to maximum of `6`, then permutations of `3,4,5` are the only positive integer solutions to the right triangle.

Comment: Ok. I've changed it to `between(1,6,X),between(1,6,Y),between(1,6,Z),(Z^2 =:= Y^2 + X^2).` so that the output will not be misleading. How do I distinguish `3,4,5` from `4,3,5` which are the same?

Comment: Note to self: read comments before answering by inadvertently repeating what already has been said. @mbratch, don't you want to turn your comments into an answer?

Comment: @nobodynoone You could add something like `Y >= Z`.

Comment: By the way, the tag `pascals-triangle` is not appropriate here since this problem is not directly related to Pascal triangles. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle.

Comment: My mistake, thanks though for catching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the prolog manual regarding the different comparators, etc. They mean and do various things. `=:=/2` is specifically evaluates arithmetic expressions on either side and checks for equality of results. `=/2` is not an equality operator; it performs prolog unification. It's important to know the difference. In your example, limiting all results to maximum of `6`, then permutations of `3,4,5` are the only positive integer solutions to the right triangle.

```
?- between(1,6,X), between(1,6,Y), between(1,6,Z), Z^2 =:= X^2 + Y^2.
X = 3,
Y = 4,
Z = 5 ;
X = 4,
Y = 3,
Z = 5 ;
false.
```

Comment: You could add `X <= Y` to prevent the permutation showing up.

Comment: @SQB yep, good idea. I wasn't sure what the OP's specific requirements were in that regard.